# Apple VOIP Push notification server

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

So, i'm developing a [IOS VOIP app](https://apps.apple.com/br/app/vmax-fone/id1511737051), and find out that i need to use a Push notification server to make my app work on background to receive incoming calls and etc.

I searched and dont find anything about **how can i set-up, develop, use, find about, a push notification server/gateway**

I found some server who are paid and dont help me on anything, because i can't pay it right now.

I'm sorry to write a question entirely of text, with no code, but there's no code to use right now.

Yes i read the documentation, and articles, and etc, but they just talk about "Setup your server and send a push to apns", nothing useful about what i should use or how can i set-up a server.

Here's what i already found about it:

[Mizu VOIP push gateway](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Portals/0/Files/documentation/PushProxy/index.html)

[How to create a native iOS app that can receive VoIP push notifications](https://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/)

[Session Talk push gateway](https://www.sessiontalk.co.uk/help-articles/voip-softphone-push-server-setup)

[Mizu VOIP Push notifications](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Portals/0/Files/VOIP_Push_notifications.pdf)

[Push notifications docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit?language=objc)

In case doesn't exist a non-paid alternative to a push notification server/gateway, is there a workaround to this problem with the newest IOS changes? (I found something like a workaround said by the Zoiper team [here](https://www.zoiper.com/en/support/home/article/205/Zoiper%20Push%20Proxy))

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

The solution was using the Flexisip proxy server.

Comment: The protocol to send to Apple is the same for voip and standard and is documented here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/. Additionally you will find lots of open source client implementations for python, JavaScript, Perl, php etc.  A VoIP push just includes voip in the payload.

Comment: @Paulw11 -  "A VoIP push just includes voip in the payload." I am using pushy library for apns that uses a pushy token. For doing voip, does it also require a voip token provided by the apple phone?

Comment: The token from the phone is the same for VoIP push and regular push. A VoIP push includes VoIP in the message payload.